# Using Carbon in html response frm ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, php-carbon

In the below code, I want to show updated some hours ago since the data is updated, but `' + $item.updated_at->diffInHours(now()) + '` giving following error **Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '>'** It is pointing at -> operator

Any Suggestion is appreciated, Thanks

**index.blade.php**

```
<script>
...

function fetchAllNames() {
        var _url = '{{ route("names.fetch.route") }}';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: _url,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {                        
                $('tbody').html("");
                $.each(response.name, function($key, $item) {
                    $('tbody').append('<tr>\
                        <td><input type="checkbox" id="sub_master" data-id="' + $item.id + '"></td>\
                        <td>' + $key + '</td>\
                        <td>' + $item.name + '</td>\                            
                        <td><label id="timeLabel">' + $item.updated_at->diffInHours(now()) + '</label></td>\
                    \</tr>');
                });
            }
        });               
    }

...
</script>
```

**CustomController.php**

```
public function FetchName() 
{ 
    $name = CandidateName::all(); 
    return response()->json(['name'=>$name]); 
}
```

Comment: I think you are trying to use php inside javascript. `$` is used in PHP to declare a variable, there is no need for that in Javascript. Also you are trying to call `diffInHours(now())` which is a Carbon method (PHP) on a javascript object, you need to do this calculation in the controller before sending the response from `route("names.fetch.route")`. Or you could calculate it in Javascript.

Comment: `$item` is a variable of jQuery and `diffInHours` is a method of PHP, you cannot call PHP method using jQuery variable.

Comment: i think "->" isn't valid in javascript, if $item.updated_at has a function called diffInHours() then you would use a . (dot) to reference it. You might be getting mixed up with php vs javascript. You would have to either use some javascript function to get the difference, or work out the time diff on the php side and send it along with the response.

Comment: @Loopo right, I am doing that way but getting error now is not defined
    public function FetchName()
    {
        $name = CandidateName::all();
        return response()->json(['name'=>$name]);       
    }
Can I calculate this difference inside my controller ?

Comment: I would probably do it on the client side, you could then even update the diff as time passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $item.updated_at is a string with a datetime such as '2022-04-01 12:12:00'.
You can define a javascript function

```
function diffInHoursToNow(dateStr){
   var inputDate = new Date(Date.parse(dateStr));
   var diff = new Date().getTime() - inputDate.getTime();
   //depending on what you want you can round this off with 
   //Math.floor(diff/3600)/1000 or similar 
   return diff/3600000;
}
```

and then when generating your table row you can call

```
<td><label id="timeLabel">' + diffInHoursToNow($item.updated_at) + '</label></td></tr>'
```

Although it's valid and can be useful on occasion, you probably don't want to use $ to start your javascript variable names ($key and $item). This will help to remove the temptation to call php functions.

Answer (score 1):

**you cant use PHP in the response to ajax,**
you have two options whether to handle it in PHP
before return response or use can handle it via js,
also please check this   [moment.js Library](https://momentjs.com/) its  Javascript library that manipulates dates like `Carbon` library

should be something like that
at render you html

```
var now = moment(new Date()); //todays date
var end = moment($item.updated_at); // another date

 $('tbody').append('<tr>\
                        <td><input type="checkbox" id="sub_master" data-id="' + $item.id + '"></td>\
                        <td>' + $key + '</td>\
                        <td>' + $item.name + '</td>\                            
                        <td><label id="timeLabel">' + moment.duration(now.diff(end))  + '</label></td>\
                    \</tr>');
```

Comment: Thank you for the library suggestion, its worked